# CSS grid-row attribute compiled incorrectly by Less

Tags: css, less, css-grid

I'm trying to set the grid-row property of a CSS Grid item to an area spanning two rows. For example:

```
.example-class{
   grid-column: 1;
   grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
```

The CSS properties in the broswer are shown as:

```
.example-class{
   grid-column: 1;
   grid-row: 0.333333;
}
```

Based on [CSS Tricks' CSS Grid guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/#prop-grid-column-row-start-end), my grid-row property is correct syntax to create a grid track between row 1 and 3. Why is this building incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [Escaping](http://lesscss.org/functions/)

```
grid-row: e("1 / 3");
```

Comment: This works, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
grid-row: ~"1 / 3";
```

How do you compiled your Less ?

Answer (score 0):

Your 1 / 3 is being interpreted as a calc, resulting 0.333333;